# Select a different keystroke than colon ':' to enter command-line mode in vi

Tags: vim, vi

Is there any way to achieve that remapping?  I looked a bit into

> ```
> map
> ```

and

> ```
> inoremap
> ```

but they appear to affect *within* a given mode, not how to enter a given mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `nmap`, e.g.,

```
:nmap ; :
```

to [map semicolon to colon](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_semicolon_to_colon). The 'n' in `nmap` indicates normal mode.

If you wanted to use, say, the `<F2>` function key to enter command-line mode from insert mode, you can do:

```
:imap <F2> <Esc>:
```

There's an exhaustive 3-part tutorial about key mappings in vim [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29).

Comment: ah **n**map i.e normal mode mapping. this is what I am looking for